# RethinkDB error codes on inserting duplicate primary key

Tags: rethinkdb

What is the best way to handle the error that is thrown when a row with an existing primary key is being inserted.

rethinkdb returns 'Duplicate primary key...' in first_error.

Currently this is how I am handling it:

```
        if result['errors'] > 0 and 'Duplicate primary key' in result['first_error']:
```

But this seems very brittle, does rethinkdb also return error codes along with error string messages.

Answer (score 1):

The driver don't return specific error codes, so I think the code you have now is probably the best way to go. Just keep in mind that these messages are sent directly by the server (not the driver), so if they change, they would have to change at the database level.

If you feel getting error codes would be useful, I'd suggest creating an issue in [RethinkDB's GitHub issue tracker](https://github.com/rethinkdb/rethinkdb/issues). Someone in the RethinkDB team will usually, at least, acknowledge the issue and see if they can include it in the database.